# Optimal way to sync NoSql (DynamoDB) with Elastisearch (not the AWS managed one) in local environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, logstash

I currently have aws dynamodb (port: 8000) and elasticsearch (port: 9200)+kibana(port: 5601) running locally.I pretty much spent almost half a day figuring out how to sync these services together. To provide context, I have a nextJS app running thats integrated with both clients however, when I upsert data into dynamo, Id like to get it synced with elasticsearch right away.

Note, for upper environments I plan on using aws lambdas integrated with dynamodb streams to update indexes in elasticsearch instances (I am not a fan of the aws elasticsearch managed service).

Here is what I have tried thus far for local env syncing:

1. Logstash w/dynamodb plugin (https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb) - the repo hasnt been updated in 4 years and issues support newer version of ES. Been a headache all morning trying to get the thing running due to this and other issues --> https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb/issues/10
   result: its a lost cause as far as I know... ive even tried their docker images but not workin..
2. node-scheduler: oh jeez... given Im using nextJS Id have to create a custom server just to get this extra piece synced... not to mention it removes a lot of the important features of nextJS -> https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
3. host the development dynamodb in aws (not local) + provision ES on ec2 and point local app there. I think this is overkill imo as now pretty much everything is hosted except my app, which could be ok. Let me know your thoughts as I already have dev environment using a separate cognito pool to authenticate.
4. Just chain ES calls to any updates made on dynamodb. Can someone tell me why we cant do this locally and in general? I get that data can get out of sync but maybe we can do hourly, or even twice a day (offpeak) cron jobs to bulk update the dynamo records to ES.

Would really appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by running dynamodb and elastic search locally?  I think isolating services locally makes sense if you're trying to do run end-to-end tests but for development I'm not sure I would go through that to have a local stack..

Comment: hey @MikeDinescu, my writes go to dynamodb and my reads hit elastisearch. The purpose of the syncing is to get parity. Hmm fair point, but what do you think about upserting ES directly?